# How do I use the PowerShell SDK package in a .Net Core app on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: .net, linux, powershell, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm trying to use the .Net Core PowerShell SDK to build a sample application to run on Ubuntu Linux.

I have the following code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;


var p_TestUserName = "UserName";
var p_Password = "password";
var ipAddress = "192.168.1.13";
var credentials = new PSCredential(p_UserName, ConvertToSecureString(p_Password));
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, 
                                            IPAddress, 
                                            5985, 
                                            "/wsman", 
                                            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", 
                                            credentials, 
                                            15000);
try
{
    var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
    runspace.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.AddScript("get-date");

    try
    {
        var commandOutput = ps.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The code runs correctly when I run it on Windows-64 using "localhost."
I've built, published and deployed onto my Ubuntu Linux VM.

When I attempt to run directly on the Linux box, I get the following exception:

[image: Exception from Ubuntu Linux VM]

The exception occurs when I call "**runspace.Open();**"
I have PowerShell installed on the Linux VM.
What is causing the issue?
Shouldn't the PowerShell SDK run since it's part of .NetCore?
Am I missing some packages that should be installed on the Linux VM in order for this to work?
Is this the right way to run PowerShell scripts from a .NetCore app on Linux?

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: Your error message seems to be pretty clear

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - Given what I've been reading, it's not clear WSMan is stable/available on Linux. How do I create a RemoteRunSpace on a Linux box? What is the correct method for connecting and running PowerShell scripts?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - Is it even possible to use System.Management.Automation in .NetCore on Ubuntu to create a RemoteRunSpace and run PowerShell commands? Should something other than WSMan be used? - JohnB